# Re-import old nginx logs with filebeat to logstash / elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, import, logstash, filebeat

I have some old log files from nginx that I want to import into logstash / elastic search using filebeat. These are the files in particular:

```
-rw-r----- 1 www-data adm    5822909 Feb  9 02:48 access-stream.log-2024-02-09-06.gz
-rw-r----- 1 www-data adm    8548121 Feb 10 03:11 access-stream.log-2024-02-10-06.gz
-rw-r----- 1 www-data adm   11714066 Feb 11 01:45 access-stream.log-2024-02-11-06.gz
```

I have tried following the instructions in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55206750/5660974) but the logs do not appear in elasticsearch.

To clear the old data, I stopped the filebeat and logstash services and then did:

```
POST filebeat-7.9.1-2024.02.*/_delete_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "@timestamp": {
        "gte": "now-2w"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

in Kibana dev tools which resulted in a gateway timeout, so I deleted the indexes:

```
DELETE filebeat-7.9.1-2024.02.11
```

and the ran the `delete_by_query` again that removed the old logs.

I then removed the registry and ran `filebeat -e -once` but no logs were imported. Restarting the services also did not import the logs.

Is there a way I can get these 3 log files imported again?

Comment: First, getting timeout is expected on Kibana devtool because that delete_by_query request will take so much time. You can check the _tasks endpoint to follow your task results. And could you check your path you are trying to ingest which is referring the correct folder you have old logs.